# ¿Cómo puedo leer y comparar huellas dactilares con apache cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Me están solicitando desarrollar una app la cual tendrá la función de leer la huella dactilar de un empleado y almacenarla en una base de datos. Desconozco si esto es posible con apache cordova.

Comment: Buscando en google ["apache cordova fingerprint api"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth) sale el primer resultado un tutorial facil para instalar y usar la api

Comment: No se puede, las huellas se guardan en el dispositivo pero tu no puedes acceder a ellas ni guardarlas en otros sitios, simplemente puedes comprobar en el propio dispositivo si la huella que lee es reconocida o no por el dispositivo. No es cosa de Cordova, es cosa de como esta implementado el reconocimiento de huellas en sistemas operativos, no quieren que nadie pueda almacenar huellas por motivos de privacidad.

Comment: Antes que nada investiga sobre el lector de huellas dactilares que van a utilizar, por lo que he leído suelen traer su propio Software de escaneo, así como la API o un SDK para su desarrollo.

Comment: Si estuve leyendo y tienen su propio sdk. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Solo puedo es acceder a la api de lector de huella mas no acceder a el resultado como tal? Existe algún periférico externo para lector de huella compatible con android ?

Comment: Estuve buscando y vi app que utilizan la cámara como lector de huellas Que tan seguro es a la hora de capturar y comparar la huella?